# Jenkins doesn't recognize IONIC as command

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins, ionic-framework

I'm currently setting up Jenkins for a IONIC Project of mine. 
I've got a Jenkinsfile with the following content:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {

    stage ('NPM Setup'){
        steps{
            bat 'npm install'
        }
    }

    stage('Android Build'){
        steps{
            bat 'ionic cordova build android --release'
        }
    }
}
```

}

Jenkins causes an Error with the following Errormessage:

> The "ionic" command is either misspelled or could not be found.

What am i doing wrong here or is there anything i didn't configure for it to run?
The code is stored in a git-repo if this is anything interesting.

Kind regards
Crooky

Comment: Where is `ionic` located? You propably have to add its directory to `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I forgott to restart Jenkins after i added it to the Path-Variable. I'm sorry to steal your time. Thank you so much.

Comment: Even better would be to run ionic locally in your workspace so you actually use the version that your application uses and don't corrupt the global installation.

Answer (score 1):

add ionic cli to your package.json dependencies.

use npx. This command line is bundled with node since version 5.2.0

```
stage('Android Build'){
    steps{
        bat 'npx ionic cordova build android --release'
    }
}
```